# How does Azure DevOps use variable groups for a python published artifact

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I currently am working on automating my Flask server deployment with Azure DevOps.

I have a variable group in my Azure DevOps that I use (database connections, tenant IDs, sensitive information) that typically when I ran locally was in a .env file.

I am not really familiar with how this works when the artifact is published, do I need to have the agent also create a .env?

My react app I understood, because when the agent used the variable group, it was a part of the building of the app. So I have no issue with that, but the python one seems a bit different.

I just kind of need to know the right direction with this one, I am leaning towards maybe I need to have a .env creation, and populate with the variable groups, but I am sure someone knows more about this than me.

Thanks!

Comment: Your build process should not be responsible for setting runtime parameters. This is the responsibility of your *deployment* process. Depending on what your runtime environment is, runtime configuration should be sourced from an appropriate configuration management store, such as Azure KeyVault.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick response, when you say responsibility of the deployment process, is this maybe a reference to a release pipeline? @DanielMann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after some research I think I found 4 different ways of approaching this problem. This is just from my current understanding but I could do maybe the following.

1. Just have the ENV on the VM Machine (Not confident about this one)
2. Upload a secure file in Azure DevOps and inject it with the deployment
3. Use the Azure KeyVault (suggested by @DanielMann)
4. Have a script that creates the ENV with the variable groups and have it with the artifact

I am welcome to other suggestions, but I will probably try to use #2 or #3.